# Is the word "like" wrong?

Tags: phrases, formality

Here is my example (from an SAT question):

> Like his other cookbooks, in his new book Chef Louis offers lengthy explanations of what he considers to be basic cooking principles.

The error was the phrase "Like his". I would like to make sure that it is an error because "like" is informal. Could someone explain if I am right or why it is wrong?

Comment: Correct might be: "Like his other cookbooks, Chef Louis' new book offers..."  or "As in his other cookbooks, in his new book..."

Comment: It's informal because, to be precise, it says Chef Louis is like a load of cookbooks.

Comment: Being informal usage isn't an error.  But in this case, "like" can be better rendered with "as". So I would prefer: "In his new book Chef Louis offers lengthy explanations of what he considers to be basic cooking principles, as he did (does) in all his cookbooks.". (Other is not required - obviously they are "other").

Comment: That is not an "informal" use of "like".  The error is that the adjective phrase "Like ... cookbooks" is not given a meaningful noun phrase to modify.

Comment: I think it's just "clumsy" phrasing. I'd go for *In his new book, **as with** his other cookbooks, Chef Louis offers lengthy [blah blahs]*

Comment: @Hot Licks: I agree that the "like" phrase in this sentence is not good at all, however I was responding to the OP saying "I would like to make sure that it is an error because "like" is informal." - and just that informal is not always (even often) a reason to call something an error. They definitely have to use "as" rather than "like", to my mind.

Comment: @Cargill - I did not say that "like" was a poor choice of words.  I simply said that the use of "like" being attempted was not in any way "informal".  The "informal" use is "Like, his cookbooks are excellent."  "Like" is being used in a perfectly formal fashion, only the rest of the sentence is mucked up.

Comment: @Cargill - It's all easily fixed by removing a word or two:  "Like his other cookbooks, the new book by Chef Louis offers lengthy explanations of what he considers to be basic cooking principles."

Comment: @Cargill: As Hot Licks says, *in his new book Chef Louis [does something]* is not a noun phrase. As in *He is a man like **his father***, re-ordered to *Like his father, he is a man*, so to speak. But although I can't say I particularly like *As in his other books, he does that*, it sounds a lot better to me than *Like in his other books, he does that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole question would help with this one.  I think the issue is that the noun of "like his other cookbooks" is not the same as the subject of the sentence, Chef Louis.

You could clean it up (somewhat awkwardly) by starting it "Like he does in his other cookbooks..."

Comment: GEdgar's comment is a much better rephrasing.